# How to find the information about the perforce sandbox from the client name

Tags: perforce

When Im in the client root, using the `p4 info` I can get the information about the sandbox including the client name.

But, when I know the name of the perforce client, how do I get all the information about the sandbox including the location of it

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30832027/193453

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a thing in Perforce as a "sandbox".  Usually when people use that term, they're coming from a ClearCase world and using "sandbox" to refer to the client workspace.

So if you want to know where the "sandbox" is and you've already found the "client root", you're there!  The client root is the thing you're looking for.

Comment: The thing is I haven't found the client root. I just know the name of the client. Can I extract the client root from the client name?

Comment: Run `p4 info` (like you said you did in your OP) -- the `Client root` is included in that output.